# What shall we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

I hope it's not too early to start asking what to name our chat room.

One name per answer, please.

Answer (score 7):

**Lost in Translation**

A sort of play on how things can be confusing in a new land, so you come on here to find out what it means :)

Comment: I like this one a lot

Comment: This seems more appropriate for Linguistics to me :)

Comment: Linguists never get lost in translation d-;

Answer (score 7):

## The Embassy

Much less 'official' than my previous suggestion, yet surely familiar and welcoming to expats :)

Comment: Embassies aren't official? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

**The Consulate**

Much like The Embassy, I just like saying the word more :)

Comment: "Consulate" is also more often used in other languages than "Embassy" I think.

Comment: "Consulate" is used a lot more than "Embassy" in general, as there is ever, at most, one Embassy per foreign country, but there are often multiple consulates.

Answer (score 6):

**The Outpost**

Just sounds remote and kinda cool - the place to find others like yourself.

Comment: Sounds more like a Fort on a Frontier then expat related... Somehow this always associates with Mos Eisley for me...

Answer (score 4):

**Without Borders**

Referring to the fact that the chat is open, and borders don't matter. (I originally wanted to use the Chat Sans Frontières, which would refer to [Jeux Sans Frontières](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeux_Sans_Fronti%C3%A8res), international TV competitions, but I found out that in English, the French title is used, and that would be confusing.)

Comment: Oh, how I miss that show

Answer (score 2):

## The other side

Comment: This reminds me too much of [John Edward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Edward). :P

Answer (score 2):

### The Neutral Zone

Answer (score 2):

**Papers Please**

In the style of yester-year

Answer (score 2):

**Over There**

Because it's about asking questions about that distant place rather than where you're from.

Answer (score 1):

**The New Life**

Most move for a particular reason, for a better job, life, health etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Somewhere Else**

Because you used to live *somewhere* but now you're going to live *somewhere else*.

Because we have the main site, the meta site, and the chat room is *somewhere else*.

Answer (score 0):

## The Between

Because we are

Comment: Or **In Between**, or just **Between**, then we can say "I'm in Between" :)

Answer (score 0):

### All Other Passports

Because that's the (usually extremely crowded, slow) line I have to get in at the airport whenever I come home - as opposed to the one (**local passports** - usually not at all crowded) that my wife gets to use.

Answer (score -1):

**Frontier**

Because it means "border" literally, which separate countries. You'll cross one or more when you expatriate.

But it also means a new expanse of the world at its edge, the chatroom is where you'll discuss the new frontiers that the site might pursue, as in making decisions about scope and policy.

Answer (score -1):

## **Exile**

Because it's funny (-:

Unless you have no sense of humour.

Or unless you have actually been forcibly exiled.

But then again maybe you've been forcibly exiled but still have a great sense of humour (-:

There are also totally random reasons to like it: It's really short. It starts with the same first two letters as the site name.

Answer (score -2):

### [We're not in Kansas any more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQLNS3HWfCM)

Not to plug my home state... I'm actually rather ashamed that this is the only thing *anyone* anywhere knows about Kansas...  But it seems appropriate.

[image]

Comment: LOL - excellent choice, except for those who are relocating there of course.

Comment: Except I would make it "You're not in Kansas any more"

Comment: @Karlson: The direct quote from the movie is [We're not in Kansas any more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQLNS3HWfCM).

Comment: I don't get the reference. It seems odd to chose some (presumably) US-centric cultural reference for a site about living abroad.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans Wizard of Oz.

Comment: I think just about all native English speakers would get the reference, except perhaps the very young. It's not US-centric any more than the language here being English is England-centric.

Answer (score -2):

#### The Adjustment Bureau

I do like "The Embassy" but embassies serve a much broader purpose and clientele than the expatriate community.

This is an effort to capture that "special expat twist" - the inevitable adjustments that come with a new context.

Answer (score -2):

Trailblazer :)

A person who is the first to do something; an innovator!!!

Answer (score -3):

**Destination Abroad**

---