# Shouldn't we just merge the chat box of travel.se and expat.se?

Tags: discussion, chat

There is a [poll](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-shall-we-name-our-chat-room) going on for a name for the chatbox. Wouldn't merging both chatbox, make sense since both audience share relocating?

Comment: I would disagree.  While the contingent may be similar it is not necessarily the same.

Comment: Don't forget to merge with the workplace chatroom since many will be migrating for work. And the StackOverflow chatroom since many migrating for work will be software developers ...

Answer (score 8):

These are two entirely *separate* communities. Entering a chat room shared between two sites would be a bit disconcerting and unexpected. Users would likely find a group of users discussing things that are entirely off topic and out of context from the site they just came from. We do not support this configuration in any case.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be the first time people in travel.se would discuss programming or football

Comment: @Andra Yes, but it's two different communities indulging a bit in relaxed banter. There's also nothing stopping folks from participating in both rooms, often simultaneously, and chat messages from one room magically 'one box' if quoted in another. It's _integrated_, but should be kept separate.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing stopping anyone from establishing a brand new room that has the declared purpose of hosting both travel and expats SE contributors and conversations.

Comment: That's simply inaccurate. For example, 6 of the top 10 expats users are also among the top users on travel. And avoiding off-topic discussion is not a serious argument: the travel chat is full of unrelated chitchat and far from overloaded, the expats chat is mostly dead and when a serious issue arises, it's often about what should go where and it's just as likely to be discussed on the travel chat. Maybe you *wish* them to be separate communities and that's good reason to keep the chat rooms separate but that's not the case at the moment, as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 8):

Please no!  One of the main reasons Expat got a push was to separate the two distinct audiences.  We'll get overlap, for sure as many users who travel are expats too, but many of them are programmers too, and we're certainly not combining that with stackoverflow's chats.

Comment: +1 And for the overlap, there's nothing wrong with chatting in two rooms, I do it quite a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Please visit the brand new chat room I just built:

> **[Travelling, Expatriating, and Immigrating](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13790/travelling-expatriating-and-immigrating)**

Now we have a place to mingle.

And places to call home.